# Persistent much? (What does it mean)

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, figurative-language

Someone had written

> “**Persistent much, huh**? Well, then let’s start with my family background.”

What does “Persistent much” mean? I looked it up, but I couldn’t find it’s meaning.........

Comment: This is asked in [*this*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242062/whats-the-meaning-of-the-expression-something-much) EL&U question.

Answer (score 1):

This type of sentence structure is quite common in informal language or slang in everyday speech:

adjective + much + question mark

In the case of 'persistent' used as the adjective, this comment is supposed to mean 'wow you are very persistent'. Even though it is a question, it is a rhetorical question so you are not supposed to answer it. Other examples of this structure used with different adjectives include:

Scared much? -'You are really scared'
Tired much? -'You are clearly really tired'
Bossy much? -'You are being really bossy'
Excited much? -'You are overly excited'

It can be used as either a positive comment, and the person's body language, tone of voice, laughing etc will show you this. However, it can also be used to show annoyance or to offend. In the case of 'persistent much?', it could be either a positive joke or showing annoyance that they do not want to tell you about whatever it is you are asking about; it is up to you to analyse this from their body language.

Answer (score 0):

A good reference in the comments -

> This is asked in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242062/whats-the-meaning-of-the-expression-something-much) EL&U question. – Jason Bassford

I believe those answers are correct, and they include:

"I am pretty sure it's this slang usage..."

"The expression x much is a sarcastic expression meaning that the target of the expression is engaging in x, and is generally used when x is undesirable."